# Using Interactions to cycle Mob Spawner entities (Minecraft 23w31a)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

### The idea

I'm attempting (via data pack) to use an interaction (tagged `MobSpawner`) to cycle through a "list" of different mobs when it's right-clicked, but only after having been right-clicked once prior (i.e, when all is said and done, I want the player to "unlock" it first before it cycles; I also have it set to a stupid delay, so mobs won't spawn beforehand).

My attempts to do this so far have involved two scoreboards (named `UnlockedMob` and `MobOption` for example purposes), and various checks in a function running every tick.

### The attempts

The initial unlock check works as follows;

- Unless `UnlockMob` is already set, if the interaction entity has any interaction data, modify the spawner's Delay from insanely long to a quick time.

  - `execute as @e[type=interaction,tag=MobSpawner] unless score @s UnlockedMob matches 1 if data entity @s interaction run data modify block ~ ~ ~ Delay set value 10s`
- With the same checks, set `MobOption` for it to 1.

  - `...run scoreboard players set @s MobOption 1`
- With the same checks, set `UnlockedMob` to 1.

  - `...run scoreboard players set @s UnlockedMob 1`
- Remove the interaction data from the entity

  - `execute as @e[type=minecraft:interaction,tag=MobSpawner] run data remove entity @s interaction`

With `UnlockedMob` set to one, *in theory*, any further interactions with the entity should *not* trigger this section of code.

Then, I have code set for the following;

- If the interaction entity has any interaction data, and `MobOption` is 1, modify the spawner's entity to be a Cow.

  - `execute as @e[type=minecraft:interaction,tag=MobSpawner] if data entity @s interaction if score @s MobOption matches 1 run data modify block 10 1 10 SpawnData.entity.id set value "minecraft:cow"`
- With the same checks, set `MobOption` to 2.

  - `... run scoreboard players set @s MobOption 2`
- Remove the interaction data from the entity

  - `execute as @e[type=minecraft:interaction,tag=MobSpawner] run data remove entity @s interaction`

These commands are then basically copy-pasted, with `if score @s MobOption matches` and `scoreboard players set @s MobOption` increasing by one, until we hit the end of the "list" where I set it back to 1 again.

### The problem

I have tried every conceivable fashion of modifying this to make it work; the furthest I got was without any form of "has unlocked" check *and* without removing the interaction data, where it immediately shot to the end of the list and remained unchanged no matter what I did.

Now, however, it remains unmoved and unchanged regardless of what I try. The interaction entity isn't even getting the `MobOption` or `UnlockedMob` scores, which I've tested standalone outside the data pack both via command blocks and via the chat, and have worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The issue was due to poor firing across the board.

Because it was trying to reset itself constantly and perform a stupid number of checks, it would eventually fail on a check and refuse to run.

The resolution itself was to modularize each section into its own functions; rather than the one massive function file for each check, I now have the main function file performing checks on unlocking and/or cycling, and separate function files handling the actual unlocking and cycling.